# Using SharedPreferences between Activity

Tags: java, android

I have a configuration page which has a form on it.  When the button is pressed, I want to save that value to a SharedPreference.   This SharedPreference value then needs to be accessed from elsewhere in my app.

I am trying to save the value like the below.  I want to save the collectionID so I can use it elsewhere

```
public class ConfigPage extends Activity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    Button   mButton;
    EditText mEdit;
    String collectionID;
    String key = "GregKey";

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.config);
        getActionBar().hide();

        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setCollection);
        mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.collectionName);

        mButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        collectionID = mEdit.getText().toString();
                        Log.d("EditText", collectionID);
                        SharedPreferences settings =
                                getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                        editor.putString(key, collectionID);
                        editor.commit();
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Once it has been saved, I then need to access it in another class, however I can't figure out how to do this.  The example above crashes the application at the moment so something isn't quite right

Comment: and what does the log say?

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.greghesp.muzeicollection, PID: 20980
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.greghesp.muzeicollection/com.greghesp.muzeicollection.ConfigPage}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message

Comment: @K20GH : use `Log.d("Saved as"," " +savedID);` instead of ` Log.d("Saved as", savedID);` because savedID is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to save the collectionID so I can use it elsewhere

Use `mButton` Button `onClick` event for saving EditText text in `SharedPreferences` as :

```
 mButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
         {
            public void onClick(View view)
             {
                collectionID = mEdit.getText().toString();
                 Log.d("EditText", collectionID);
                 // save value here in SharedPreferences
                 SharedPreferences settings = 
                            ConfigPage.this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                 editor.putString(collectionID, collectionID);
                 editor.commit();
               }
         });
```

Comment: Ive used the answer from Philipp below however I have put this in the OnClick statement.  However I still get a null pointer exception from     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

Comment: Thanks,  will take a look in a minute.  Studio is giving me EOF exceptions and won't let me work..

Comment: I'm literally stumped, still failing on a null pointer of line 26 of ArtSource.java   ConfigPage.java  http://pastebin.com/wfgPXhW0   ArtSource.java http://pastebin.com/Hu69Mgxw

Comment: I think what is happening as the null pointer occurs because there is nothing set in the preferences as default?

Comment: Wow, thanks that worked.  Just need to get my head around what I was doing wrong now :)

Answer (score 1):

Your crash occurs because your value is **null**:

```
String savedID;
```

You need to add a value to the variable:

```
String savedID = "somevalue";
```

Also, **your key is null** as long as the `Button` is not pressed which will also lead to a crash.

The `putString(String key, String value)` method enables you to store a specific **value** with a specific **key**, that can later be used to reaccess the stored value.

Example:

```
String key = "somekey";
String value = "yourvaluetostore";

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(key, value); // store the value
editor.commit();
```

In another Activity:

```
String key = "somekey";
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

// get the value "" is default
String value = sharedPreferences.getString(key, "");
```

**All you need in the other Activity is the key** you stored the value with. With this key, you can pull the correct stored value out of the `SharedPreferences`. --> **The key is needed to identify the value.**

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense.  The issue I'm having in my other activity is that the getSharedPreference line can't resolve the method or symbol of PREFS_NAME

Comment: Just reuse your String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile"; in the other Activity.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I thought, just tried that.  Still getting that null error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.greghesp.muzeicollection.ArtSource: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Yes, please read my full answer carefully. I already mentioned that.

Comment: I have removed savedID as it was no longer needed.  I'm just using key and collectionID.  The null pointer seems to refer to     SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the part of code :

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(collectionID, savedID);
editor.commit();

Log.d("Saved as", savedID);
```

in the `onCreate` method, that translates to

```
...
editor.putString(null, null);
Log.d("Saved as", null);
```

Correct your code so that you fill those elements before. I guess you wanted to make the save in the `OnClick` part

Answer (score 0):

Yes something its not quite right here because as i see you are saving nothing. on shared pref you should have a "key" which will be use to identify the saved value in your example it should be something like this

```
public class ConfigPage extends Activity {

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
public static final String COLLECTIONID_KEY = "COLLECTIONID_KEY";
Button   mButton;
EditText mEdit;
String collectionID;
String savedID;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.config);
    getActionBar().hide();

    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setCollection);
    mEdit   = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.collectionName);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    collectionID = mEdit.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("EditText", collectionID);
                }
            });

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString(COLLECTIONID_KEY, collectionID);
    editor.commit();

    Log.d("Saved as", COLLECTIONID_KEY);
}
```

}

then to retrieve it :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
String mySavedCollectionID = sharedPreferences.getString(COLLECTIONID_KEY);
```

and make sure that its done on the Onclick event otherwise you might end up with crash again because after the on-click event in your code the lines below will run anyway and save null!